# java.lang.ClassCastException com.google.android.gms.iid.zzh.onServiceConnected Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

We are having huge crash reports > 200k on android version 8.0 and 8.1.
Error we are getting

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: 
  at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzh.onServiceConnected (zzh.java:4)
  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected (LoadedApk.java:1631)
  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run (LoadedApk.java:1660)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:789)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:98)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:172)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6637)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:240)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Few devices which are getting this error are Oneplus5, 5T, galaxy s8, MI A1

Comment: we upgraded all the library to latest and removed gcm.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue, which seems to be caused by different version of libs, because I've got an error tip in build.gradle:

> "all gms/firebase libaries must use the exact same version. Found versions 15.1.0, 15.0.2, 15.0.1, 15.0.0."

Update all the libs to newest version may solve this problem.